# MS Access Query - To get customer ID which has different names in the different field

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016, access-database-engine

I have two column one is Address ID and another one is Customer Name. below table is for reference

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 0608 | Internet company |
| 3623 | Authority |
| 3623 | Authority |
| 5478 | Group Holdings (Pty) Ltd. |
| 5478 | Shankara |
| 5478 | Group Holdings (Pty) Ltd. |

In MS access I want to retrieve **5478  Shankara** similar records.

Please help to write a MS access DB query to get records with same Address ID having different Customer names.

Comment: Write query that finds all records with ID 5478. Not really clear what your issue is nor what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @June7, From the table I want to retrive the records which has same CUST ID but the NAME is different using MS access DB . Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```sql
Select * 
From YourTable
Where [Address ID] In 
    (Select [Address ID] 
    From YourTable
    Group By [Address ID] 
    Having Count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Let me try thanks.

Comment: Tried but no luck.

Comment: Then your data are different from the sample posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the Ids related to different names by using a sub-SELECT with a DISTINCT keyword. This eliminates duplicates where the name is the same for one Id.

```sql
SELECT CustId
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CustId, Name FROM mytable)
GROUP BY CustId
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

This returns only the corresponding `CustId` once. If you want all fields of these records, you can use the above query as nested SELECT

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE CustId IN (
    SELECT CustId
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CustId, Name FROM mytable)
    GROUP BY CustId
    HAVING Count(*) > 1
)
```

If you want all combinations only once, you can add DISTINCT again:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CustId, Name FROM mytable
WHERE CustId IN (
    SELECT CustId
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CustId, Name FROM mytable)
    GROUP BY CustId
    HAVING Count(*) > 1
)
```

And there are probably other variants. It depends on the exact specification (which is not very clear to me).

Comment: I think distinct wont work in MS access DB.

Comment: Yes it works. Access SQL is in fact JET SQL: [ALL, DISTINCT, DISTINCTROW, TOP Predicates (Microsoft Jet SQL)](https://documentation.help/MS-Jet-SQL/dasqlalldistinct.htm).